How to customize pop-up footnote text in quarto blog?
I am recently trying to make a quarto blog and, although it seems not a big issue, I have a trouble on figuring out how to customize the pop-up footnote text when footnotes-hover option in the YAML is set to true. To be more specific about what I am looking for, I would like to be able to customize the footnote text (changing its font,color, size and etc) displaying on the pop-up, when the user carries the mouse on the footnote number as can be seen in the below screenshot.

As seen, I am able to change the appearance of the footnote number with the following line customized css code;
.footnote-ref {
  font-family: 'Geogrotesque Trial', sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 1em; /* Adjust font size */
  color: #56A0D3; /* Change text color */
  font-weight: 500;
}

I am also able to make changes on the footnote section, as I wish, with the following line of css code;
/* Customize the footnotes section heading */
.footnotes h2 {
  font-family: 'Geogrotesque Trial', sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 1.4em; /* Adjust font size */
  color: #333; /* Change text color */
}

/* Customize the footnote list items */
.footnotes ol {
  font-family: 'Geogrotesque Trial', sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 0.85em; /* Adjust font size */
  color: #666; /* Change text color */
}

/* Customize the footnote content */
.footnotes ol li p {
  font-family: 'Geogrotesque Trial', sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 0.7em; /* Adjust font size */
  color: #666; /* Change text color */
}

However, I have difficulty to change the pop-up footnote text, as shown in the above screenshot, when I carry my mouse over the footnote.

Is this question still open? If yes, could you consider reacting on given answers with a description what's missing? What should I do when someone answers my question?

The hover box has a .tippy-box CSS class. You can try the following to customize its text:
.tippy-box {
  color: red !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  /*...*/
}

